# Comparmentalize HTML via Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm trying to come up with a purely front-end solution to a common practice.

In the past, I've stored the HTML for reused website elements (like the `<nav>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc.) in a `functions.php` file, and used php functions to call these things in on multiple pages. This of course makes it easier to make changes site-wide, making my life easier.

However, I don't really want to use PHP (or in the past, ASP) to do this anymore. Does any one know of a clean way to do this in Javascript, jQuery or even Node? To be clear I want to call a function in the HTML (like `writeNav();` ) that pulls the HTML for the nav. I'd rather not include `<script>` tags everywhere, if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to rely on the client for this? If you plan on making AJAX calls for each element, the amount of requests to load each page increases greatly, and your site may load slowly for people with bad internet connections, on mobile devices, or with slow computers. At least make sure your site degrades gracefully.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is true. It's really not much to do with AJAX calls -- the content will always be the same and not be tied to a database. I'm just trying to compartmentalize the code to make the website scale more easily and the changes more localized (only change one page to change the nav on all sort-of thing)

Comment: There's actually some back and forth on this nowadays as ajax and JS in general move a lot faster than they used to. I still favor reduced request loads as too much back and forth can still be brutal in mobile but simple ajax requests will be cached in browsers.

Comment: `I don't really want to use PHP`. Why not? A server side solution is far more robust and will always outperform the same functionality done on the client, not to mention be more reliable and robust. Stop thinking in terms of "I want" and more in terms of "what's the best way to deliver what my visitors want". And that, in the vast majority of cases, is a fast, stable website that delivers useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very common solution for "building up a library of chunks of HTML that can be reused elsewhere" is "templating".  There are numerous templating libraries to choose from (Underscore even has its own, small, template function), but I'd recommend looking at Handlebars.js first, as it's very robust but also very simple.

Handlebars templates will allow you to store your HTML however you want:

- in strings in your .js files,
- in `<script type='text/handlebars'>` tags on your html pages, or
- in separate html files that get compiled in to a single JS file

It will also allow you to swap out small pieces of the HTML, so that you could (for instance) have a header that gets used all over, but replaces the title, like so:

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
```

The Handlebars site (http://handlebarsjs.com/) has an excellent run through; I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with jQuery, e.g.

```
function writeP(str){
    document.write($('<p />').text(str).get(0));
}
```

You could then do something like:

```
<div class="foo">
    <script type="text/javascript">writeP('hello');</script>
</div>
```

...which would result in:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

That example is silly, but I believe the mechanism is in the spirit of what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Cheers

Comment: -1—using jQuery doesn't make it any more sensible to use existing page content to replace existing page content with `document.write`.

Comment: @RobG Huh? Op said, "To be clear I want to call a function in the HTML (like writeNav(); ) that pulls the HTML for the p".  My example was similar, call `writeP('hello')` and it "pulls the HTML for the nav".  I inferred from his question that he also wanted to write it to the document.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about are html includes.

This is not really a production worthy solution, but gets me through the prototyping phase.

Using jQuery, include this in your $(document).ready() callback:

```
$(".include").each(function() {
    var inc = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : inc.attr("title"),
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(data) {
        inc.replaceWith(data);
        console.log("adding " + inc.attr("title"));
    });
```

Then in the body wherever you want to include an html file, do this:

```
<div class="include" title="path/to/html/file.html"></div>
```

All elements (divs, spans, etc) with the "include" attribute will be replaced by the content of the file path in the title attribute.

Note: the entire tag will be replaced in this process.

Comment: Just a note, you can remove `var inc = $(this)` if you add this option to your `$.ajax`: `context: $(this)` now you can just do `this.replaceWith(data)`

Answer (score 0):

There are also text editors like BBEdit with include support if it's just about organizing how you write your HTML.